# Google Kickstart 2018, Round error in test case

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I'm trying to solve the [Scrambled Words](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050edf/0000000000051004) problem in Google Kickstart 2018, Round A.

I'm having trouble generating the input string. Here are the directions they gave

> The third line contains two lowercase English letters S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub>, and
>   five integers N, A, B, C and D. S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub> are the first two characters
>   of the professor's string S, N is the length of S, and the other four
>   integers are parameters that you should use to generate the characters
>   of S, as follows:
>
> First we define ord(c) as the decimal value of a character c and
>   char(n) as the character value of a decimal n. For example, ord('a') =
>   97 and char(97) = 'a'. You can refer to ASCII table for other
>   conversions.
>
> Now, define x<sub>1</sub> = ord(S<sub>1</sub>), x<sub>2</sub> = ord(S<sub>2</sub>). Then, use the recurrence below
>   to generate x<sub>i</sub> for i = 3 to N:
>
> - x<sub>i</sub> = ( A * x<sub>i-1</sub> + B * x<sub>i-2</sub> + C ) modulo D.
>
> We define S<sub>i</sub> = char(97 + ( x<sub>i</sub> modulo 26 )), for all i = 3 to N.

Using these directions for the test input,

```
1
5
axpaj apxaj dnrbt pjxdn abd
a a 50 1 1 1 30
```

The string that I am generating is

`aapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaapaa`

But the string that is supposed to be generated is

`aapxjdnrbtvldptfzbbdbbzxtndrvjblnzjfpvhdhhpxjdnrbt`

Here is my code

```
    char S1, S2;
    long N, A, B, C, D;
    cin >> S1 >> S2 >> N >> A >> B >> C >> D;
    A %= D;
    B %= D;
    C %= D;

    vector<char> S;
    S.push_back(S1);
    S.push_back(S2);

    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
      long xi1 = (long)S[i - 1];
      long xi2 = (long)S[i - 2];
      long xi = (A * xi1) % D;
      xi += ((B * xi2) % D);
      xi += C;
      xi %= D;
      xi %= 26;

      char Si = (char)(97 + xi);
      S.push_back(Si);
    }
```

Comment: If you are trying to read `axpaj apxaj dnrbt pjxdn abd` with `std::cin >> some_std_string`, that won't work. It will only read `axpaj` and then stop. You will need to use [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: I read those in separately, beforehand, and there weren't any errors. I read each word using a loop, because the number of words is given to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you assume that S_i == x_i which is wrong. The recurrence formula is defined with x_i, not S_i, consider code below

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    long N = 4;
    long A = 1;
    long B = 1;
    long C = 1;
    long D = 30;

    std::string s = "aa";
    int xi1 = 97;
    int xi2 = 97;
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++) {
      std::cout<<(int)xi1<<" "<<xi2<< " vs si:"<<(int)s[i-1]<<" "<<(int)s[i-2]<<std::endl;
      int xi = (A*xi1 + B*xi2 + C)%D;
      char si = 97 + (xi%26);
      std::cout<<"xi: "<<xi<<" vs "<<(int)si<<std::endl;
      s += si;
      xi2 = xi1;
      xi1 = xi;
      std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"------------------------"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
97 97 vs si:97 97
xi: 15 vs 112
aap
------------------------
15 97 vs si:112 97
xi: 23 vs 120
aapx
------------------------
```